# Performance - recurrence for the expected number of recursive calls

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms, algorithmic-randomness

Here's what the following code is doing:

The randomized algorithm selects the k-th smallest element in an unsorted array *A[1...n]*, *1 < k < n*.

For simplicity of analysis it is assumed that all the elements are diefferent, so that the *k-th* smallest is well-defined: the element with exactly *k-1* elements smaller than it.

```
RandomSelect(A[1...n], k)
  p <- Random(1, n)
  r <- Partition(A[1...n], p)
  if k < r then
     return (RandomSelect(A[1...r - 1], k))
  else if k > r then
     return (RandomSelect(A[r + 1...n], k - r))
  else
    return A[r]
```

I know that ***Partition*** runs in linear time.

***Partition*** splits the array into two
parts corresponding to the elements smaller and larger than the pivot, placed to the left and right of
the pivot, whose position is returned by the function.

***Random (1, n)*** returns an integer in 1, 2,..., n uniformly at random (each integer equally likely).

I do not really understand how to write a recurrence for the expected number of recursive calls the algorithm performs.
Hopefully someone can help me, please

I think I'm supposed to write a recursive routine that will return the expected number of calls for an input array of size n. And the algorithm selects the k-th smallest element of this array A[1..n] (and A[1..n] is unsorted)

Comment: Who is **RandomSelect**?

Comment: sorry I forgot something, the whole algorithm is called RandomSelect, just edited it. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: What do you mean by "write a recurrence for the expected number of recursive calls"? Are you supposed to write a recursive routine that will return the expected number of calls for a particular input array and $k$? Are you looking for a recursion formula for the sequence $E(n,k)$ for the expected number of recursive calls for arbitrary arrays? Something else?

Comment: I think I'm supposed to write a recursive routine that will return the expected number of calls for an input array of size n. And the algorithm selects the k-th smallest element of this array A[1..n] (and A[1..n] is unsorted).